# Parallax Scrolling CSS Problems

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax

I am currently having an issue with parallax scrolling. I am using a custom JavaScript solution which moves the content over the initial background image. It works totally fine, however, the initial background photo is still visible underneath the content. Here are some code snippets.

```
#home {
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height: auto;
}

#home_img {

min-width: 100vw;
width: 100vw;
height:auto;
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
}
#content {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

And here is my html

```
<section class="section"id="home">
    <img id="home_img"src="images/homepagenew2.png">
    <!-- <i class="fa fa-home"></i> -->
</section> <!-- End Home Div -->

<div id="content">
   .....
</div>
```

Comment: Update, I am aware that when I remove the position type, z-index does not work. But when I do, it no longer renders in the background, however, there is no more parallax effect.

Comment: A [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help. Don't forget to give your `#content` element a `background-color`.